# Two Express "app"s in one NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to be able to pass different requests through different Express middleware stacks.

I think I need two express `app`s, and some way to branch.  e.g.:

```
var app = express();
var alt_app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (some_condition(req)) {
    divert_request_to_alt_app();
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

app.use(middleware_that_must_not_affect_alt_app());
alt_app.use(middleware_that_only_affects_alt_app());
```

Is such a strategy possible?

If so, what should `divert_request_to_alt_app()` be?

If not, what are other approaches?

Comment: When you say "one NodeJS *server*" do you really mean "one NodeJS *process*"? Assuming you mean process, here's an [example](http://nerdpress.org/2012/04/20/hosting-multiple-express-node-js-apps-on-port-80/) of how you can host multiple apps under a single process.

Comment: Use [routers](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router).

Comment: Have you tried using the [node http proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)?

Comment: @James I mean one HTTP server in one NodeJS process.

Comment: Does your "alt" app have different routes to your main app?

Comment: @BenFortune No, routing to the alt_app depends on only the hostname, at the moment, but I may need it to depend on other parts of `req`.

Comment: @chrisdew have a look at the example I posted, it shows how you can route different requests to different express instances based on host name.

Comment: @James the vhost example looks like it is not for express 4.x - the post is dated 2012.  There are confusingly two vhost modules on npm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that express apps are functions.  Calling them with `(req, res, next)` is all you need to do to pass a request from one app to another.

In the example below, I have one root app `app` and two branches `app0` and `app1`.

```
var app0 = require('./app0');
var app1 = require('./app1');

var app = express();
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (some_condition_on(req)) {
    app0(req, res, next);
  } else {
    app1(req, res, next);
  }
});
```